# Geometry Nodes - Incremental increases & controls

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I found [this youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2wVTGzSwpg) which shows exactly what I'm trying to do. At about the 10 second mark of the linked video, he shows controls working as integers. That in a nutshell is what I want to do.

---

I'm trying to figure out how to use Geometry Nodes but I'm starting at a pretty low level of understanding. There is a project I want to develop that I've broken down into a bunch of simpler tasks that I need to learn how to do. This is one of them. I'm using Blender 2.93 beta.

I want to be able to translate and scale by specific increments. Attached is a screen capture showing my node tree and the modifiers tab. I've used the Math node "Snap" to set an increment of 1 unit for scaling. That actually does what I want, only adjusting the cube by 1 unit increments. Success!.... however, the X (Width), Y (Depth) and Z (Height) are connected to the Group Input to give me a control for each under Geometry Nodes in the Modifiers Tab but these controls don't conform to the 1 unit increment. Currently they increase by 0.001 units at a time not by 1. Is there a way of making those controls conform?
[image]

---

Re: [Chris's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86978/chris) answer, This in some ways produce something which is another way of doing the same thing I already did with the snap function plus have added an offset which could be useful. This isn't what I was trying to resolve though. I've attached another pic. On it I've written the length of each of the sides, w=3, D=2 and H=1,but the controls on the right hand side say something different they say W= 3.37 etc These are the pre snapped sizes.

I want the controls on the right hand side (Width, Depth, Height) to say the actual size not the pre.snapped size. In other words the controls themselves should reflect the snap/rounding that is set inside the geometry node tree. Can this be done? [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input sockets can be forced integers, but you have to use a workaround if you're going to plug them into nodes that use float values.

You can use any node that has an integer input type, for instance the *Level* input of the *Subdivide* node. Integers have dark green sockets. Plug a new input from the *Group Input* node into the *Level* socket.

[image]

Delete the *Subdivide* node. You can now plug the *Level* integer input into any socket. Blender will automatically convert to the target type if possible.

```
╔═══════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╗
║ Integer - v     ║ Conversion                 ║
╠═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╣
║ Float           ║ Rounded                    ║
║ Boolean         ║ False if v <= 0, else True ║
║ Vector          ║ v => (v, v, v)             ║
║ Color           ║ v => RGB(v, v, v)          ║
║ Geometry        ║ Unsupported                ║
║ String          ║ Unsupported                ║
║ Material        ║ Unsupported                ║
║ Texture         ║ Unsupported                ║
╚═══════════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

[image]

To change the Min and Max values of the input, expand the N panel with shortcut <kbd>N</kbd> or by cliking on the arrow in the top right of the shader editor or click on View > Sidebar. There, click on the input and it will expand its properties.

[image]

Comment: wow...cool workaround!! Love it!

Comment: @Chris Developers are working on dynamic type switching in the node properties so it won't be needed for long I hope :)

Comment: i hope too... ;)

Comment: Not sure I get it just reading it but I'm about to go to work so I'll have a crack at it later today. Thanks very much Gorgious and I concur with the idea that the node properties is the place for a control switch. (I think you can already do that with Animation Nodes.)

Comment: Yes it works great - I used the Triangulate Node to get the Level output from. My little test no longer needs the Snap Maths Node.  Thanks again Gorgious the question is answered and solved.

Comment: Good tip thanks! I was momentarily confused - the tick is grey and turns green when you click on it!

Comment: Outdated (already implemented) ... Hard to say if make it sense to update the answer, since I'm not sure someone is looking for this kind of question :)

Comment: @vklidu it does make sense I think, the UI can be confusing to newcomers and I'm sure it'd help at least some people down the line.

Comment: OK so may I ask you ...? :)

Comment: @vklidu hehe I'll add on my todo list, in the meantime if you or anyone reading this feels like it, feel free to add as another answer :p